# extract text between the two blocks using regex

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I am trying to extract the text between the two strings using the following regex.

```
(?s)Non-terminated Pods:.*?in total.\R(.*)(?=Allocated resources)
```

This regex looks fine in regex101 but somehow does not print the pod details when used with `perl` or `grep -P`.  Below command results in empty output.

```
kubectl describe  node |perl -le '/(?s)Non-terminated Pods:.*?in total.\R(.*)(?=Allocated resources)/m; printf "$1"'
```

Here is the sample input:

```
PodCIDRs:                     10.233.65.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:          (7 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                        CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                        ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     foo                                         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         105s
  kube-system                 nginx-proxy-kube-worker-1                   25m (1%)      0 (0%)      32M (1%)         0 (0%)         9m8s
  kube-system                 nodelocaldns-xbjp8                          100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (4%)        170Mi (10%)    7m4s
Allocated resources:
```

**Question**:

1. how to extract the info from the above output, to look like below. What is wrong in the regex or the command that I am using?

```
Namespace                   Name                                        CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                        ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     foo                                         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         105s
  kube-system                 nginx-proxy-kube-worker-1                   25m (1%)      0 (0%)      32M (1%)         0 (0%)         9m8s
  kube-system                 nodelocaldns-xbjp8                          100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (4%)
```

**Question**-2: What if I have two blocks of similar inputs. How to extract the pod details ?
Eg:

if the input is:

```
PodCIDRs:                     10.233.65.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:          (7 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                        CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                        ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     foo                                         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         105s
  kube-system                 nginx-proxy-kube-worker-1                   25m (1%)      0 (0%)      32M (1%)         0 (0%)         9m8s
  kube-system                 nodelocaldns-xbjp8                          100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (4%)        170Mi (10%)    7m4s
Allocated resources:
....some
.......random data...
PodCIDRs:                     10.233.65.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:          (7 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                        CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                        ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     foo-1                                         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         105s
  kube-system                 nginx-proxy-kube-worker-2                   25m (1%)      0 (0%)      32M (1%)         0 (0%)         9m8s
  kube-system                 nodelocaldns-xbjp3-2                          100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (4%)        170Mi (10%)    7m4s
Allocated resources:
```

Comment: Please ask only one question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `gnu-grep` you can use your regex with some tweaks:

```bash
kubectl describe  node |
grep -zoP '(?s)Non-terminated Pods:.*?in total.\R\K(.*?)(?=Allocated resources)'

  Namespace                   Name                                        CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                        ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     foo                                         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         105s
  kube-system                 nginx-proxy-kube-worker-1                   25m (1%)      0 (0%)      32M (1%)         0 (0%)         9m8s
  kube-system                 nodelocaldns-xbjp8                          100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (4%)        170Mi (10%)    7m4s
```

- Used `\K` (match reset) after `\R` to remove that line from output
- Used `-z` option to treat treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.

PS: Same regex will work with second input block as well with header line shown before each block.

---

**Alternatively** you can use any version `sed` for this job as well:

```bash
kubectl describe  node |
sed -n '/Non-terminated Pods:.*in total.*/,/Allocated resources:/ {//!p;}'

  Namespace                   Name                                        CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                        ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     foo                                         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         105s
  kube-system                 nginx-proxy-kube-worker-1                   25m (1%)      0 (0%)      32M (1%)         0 (0%)         9m8s
  kube-system                 nodelocaldns-xbjp8                          100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (4%)        170Mi (10%)    7m4s
```

Answer (score 5):

With some obvious assumptions, and keeping it close to the pattern in the question:

```
perl -0777 -wnE'
    @pods = /Non-terminated\s+Pods:\s+\([0-9]+\s+in\s+total\)\n(.*?)\nAllocated resources:/gs;
    say for @pods
' input-file
```

(note modifiers on the regex in this line, which is too wide to fit on screen: `/gs`)

---

The regex from the question works when used instead of the one in this answer (and with no `/s` modifier, as it should) on a single block of text. To work with multiple blocks the `(.*)` in it need be changed to `(.*?)`, so that it doesn't match all the way to the last `Allocated...`

The question doesn't say how precisely is that regex "*used with `perl`*"; I can't say what failed.

Comments on the command-line program above:

- The `-0777` [switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches) makes it read the file whole into a string, available in the program in the [variable `$_`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$_), to which the regex is [bound](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Binding-Operators) by default

  There is also the switch `-g`, an alias for `-0777`, available [starting with 5.36.0](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldelta#-g-command-line-flag)
- We still need the `-n` switch so that the program iterates over the "lines" of input (`STDIN` or a file). In this case the [input record separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$/) is undefined so it's all just one "line"
- The regex captures [are returned](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Extracting-matches) since the match operator is in the list context, being assigned to the array `@pods`

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following GNU `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be, setting `RS` as `Non-terminated Pods:.*Allocated resources:` for Input_file. Then in main program checking if `RT` is NOT NULL then using `gsub` function of `awk` to substitute `(^|\n)Non-terminated Pods:[^\n]*\n` OR `\nAllocated resources:\n*` with NULL in `RT` variable and then printing its value which will provide output as per shown samples.

```
awk -v RS='Non-terminated Pods:.*Allocated resources:' '
RT{
  gsub(/(^|\n)Non-terminated Pods:[^\n]*\n|\nAllocated resources:\n*/,"",RT)
  print RT
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be as following for a very big files to read line by line.

Select range of lines of interest and remove the last one which is not included into desired output.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<>) {
    if( /^  Namespace/ .. /^Allocated resources:/ ) {
        print unless /^Allocated resources:/;
    }
}

exit 0;
```

Output

```
  Namespace                   Name                                        CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                        ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     foo                                         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         105s
  kube-system                 nginx-proxy-kube-worker-1                   25m (1%)      0 (0%)      32M (1%)         0 (0%)         9m8s
  kube-system                 nodelocaldns-xbjp8                          100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (4%)        170Mi (10%)    7m4s
  Namespace                   Name                                        CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                        ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     foo-1                                       0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         105s
  kube-system                 nginx-proxy-kube-worker-2                   25m (1%)      0 (0%)      32M (1%)         0 (0%)         9m8s
  kube-system                 nodelocaldns-xbjp3-2                        100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (4%)        170Mi (10%)    7m4s
```